# Multiple PHP applications on a single PaaS server

Tags: java, php, saas

I have a system that provides CRM (SugarCRM) and CMS (WordPress) functionality on 1 Apache Server and using 1 MySQL database that they share between them. I am also running a Jasper report server on 1 Tomcat instance that uses JDBC to query the database being used by the PHP applications. This is all set up on my local network and works very well.

Now,I want to take it to the cloud. I started with Jelastic but they set up Wordpress and SugarCRM on separate stacks, each costing $28/mo minimum. Is there a PaaS option that can put all the PHP stuff on one server and all the Java stuff on another server and one database server accessible by all of them?

Answer (score 0):

With Jelastic you only pay only for the consumed resources. More detailed information about Pricing Model you also can find in the Jelastic Docs by the following link - http://docs.jelastic.com/pricing-model

FYI, you can use one PHP (JAVA etc.) environment for the several projects. For your case (PHP) you can use following article from Docs - http://docs.jelastic.com/multiple-domains-php. Also, you can use Jelastic VPS with the full root access.